# How to handle message using Spring Cloud Stream app starter TCP

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-cloud-stream

I want to use the [Spring Cloud Stream App Starter TCP Source project](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-tcp) (maven artifact) in order to be able to receive TCP message through socket/port, **process them** and then push the result to a message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ).

This TCP source project seems to do exactly what I want, but it automatically sends the received message to the output channel. So, Is there a clean way to still use the TCP source project but intercept the TCP incoming message to transform them internally before to output them to my message broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [aggregation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_aggregation).

You create an aggregated app using the source and processor.

> Spring Cloud Stream provides support for aggregating multiple applications together, connecting their input and output channels directly and avoiding the additional cost of exchanging messages via a broker. As of version 1.0 of Spring Cloud Stream, aggregation is supported only for the following types of applications:
>
> sources, sinks, processors ...
>
> They can be aggregated together by creating a sequence of interconnected applications, in which the output channel of an element in the sequence is connected to the input channel of the next element, if it exists. A sequence can start with either a source or a processor, it can contain an arbitrary number of processors and must end with either a processor or a sink.

**EDIT**

As a work around to the Source autowiring problem, you could try something like...

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TcpSourceProperties.class)
public class MyTcpSourceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Source channels;

    @Autowired
    private TcpSourceProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter(
            @Qualifier("tcpSourceConnectionFactory") AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("toMyProcessor");
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toMyProcessor", outputChannel = Source.OUTPUT)
    public byte[] myProcessor(byte[] fromTcp) {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean tcpSourceConnectionFactory(
            @Qualifier("tcpSourceDecoder") AbstractByteArraySerializer decoder) throws Exception {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setType("server");
        factoryBean.setPort(this.properties.getPort());
        factoryBean.setUsingNio(this.properties.isNio());
        factoryBean.setUsingDirectBuffers(this.properties.isUseDirectBuffers());
        factoryBean.setLookupHost(this.properties.isReverseLookup());
        factoryBean.setDeserializer(decoder);
        factoryBean.setSoTimeout(this.properties.getSocketTimeout());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EncoderDecoderFactoryBean tcpSourceDecoder() {
        EncoderDecoderFactoryBean factoryBean = new EncoderDecoderFactoryBean(this.properties.getDecoder());
        factoryBean.setMaxMessageSize(this.properties.getBufferSize());
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I did succeed creating Aggregation to internaly Sink the messages produced by the TCP Source. However, when I try to change my Sink to a Processor. I receive an error message "Field channels in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.tcp.source.TcpSourceConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:  1- Source 2- .Processor: a programmatically registered singleton". Do you know to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem; I've opened an [issue if you want to track it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/819) one solution would be to implement your own source - copy the `TcpSourceConfiguration` and add your processing directly in the source. I will edit my answer with details.

Comment: Sorry but the above code doesn't seems to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oops - sorry - remove the `@Bean` from the `@ServiceActivator`.

Comment: I pushed a fully working [app to my sandbox repo](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/so42346872).

Comment: I was just reminded that aggregated apps must be in different packages. See the comments on [issue 819](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/819). Did you use the same package for your custom processor?

Comment: No, I didn't use the same package name. I've posted my configurations and classes in the [issue 819](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/819)